# Error attempting to set up UIAutomation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ui-automation

I'm trying to follow advice here at SO to use UIAutomation in place of the likes of SendKeys, etc, and getting the show-stopping error "Error accessing the OLE Registry" however I try to do it.

I'm running XE4 in a Win7Pro 64-bit (VMWare) VM.

Following advice here and elsewhere about encountering this error messaage:

- I'm using the built-in Administrator account (in place of my own admin account where I first encountered the error).
- I've run RegSvr32 on UIAutomationCore.Dll and it reports "Call to RegisterServer succeeded".
- I have User Account Control set to "Never notify"
- I'm starting XE4 using "Run as administrator"

In XE4, I go to Component | Import Component | Import ActiveX Control, click Add and browse to \Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.Dll (or the version in SysWOW64 and I suppose a sub-question is which one I should be trying, but I get the same error with either of them).  Then I click Open and I get an error pop-up with the "Error accessing the OLE Registry" message.  Clicking the Details button shows that the error is occurring in TLib180.Bpl, the call to TLibUtils.LoadAndRegisterTypeLibrary.

I'm not sure whether I'm missing a step or doing something wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a type library like this:

1. **Component | Import Component**.
2. **Import a Type Library**.
3. Select **UIAutomationClient**.
4. Click through to the end of the wizard and on the final page select **Create Unit**.
5. Click **Finish**.

You will now have a type library derived unit named `UIAutomationClient_TLB` that you can use like any other. You can gain access to an `IUIAutomation` interface with:

```
Automation := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
```

And at that point you are up and running.

You don't need to register anything. This is a system component that is already registered. You really don't need to be changing UAC settings, or running elevated.

Comment: I discovered this moments before reading your answer but many thanks anyway.  "You really don't need to be changing UAC settings, or running elevated." - Indeed.  However, regarding "already registered", I'm not 100% certain but I could have sworn there was nothing in the Type Library pop-up beginning with "uia" until after I used RegSvr32 - I'll try and roll back the VM later and check.